# Simpler Javascript for multiple HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I must start with I am quite a javascript novice.

Currently I am making a website where a whole bunch of items are listed. Each item has a default image and 3 images of different angles of the product. I am using JQuery to show a full sized image over the default when the user hovers over the thumbnail.

My question, I have about 90 items. Is there an easier way to do this only in javascript, without having to nest 90 items.

It must be only HTML / CSS / Javascript

Currently for 3 items it would like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// First thumbnail on each item
  $("#thumb1-1,#thumb2-1,#thumb3-1").hover(function(){
    $("#image1-1,#image2-1,#image3-1").show();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").hide();
  },function(){
    $("#image1-1,#image2-1,#image3-1").hide();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").show();
  });

// Second thumbnail on each item
  $("#thumb1-2,#thumb2-2,#thumb3-2").hover(function(){
    $("#image1-2,#image2-2,#image3-2").show();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").hide();
  },function(){
    $("#image1-2,#image2-2,#image3-2").hide();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").show();
  });

// Third thumbnail on each item

  $("#thumb1-3,#thumb2-3,#thumb3-3").hover(function(){
    $("#image1-3,#image2-3,#image3-3").show();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").hide();
  },function(){
    $("#image1-3,#image2-3,#image3-3").hide();$("#default1,#default2,#default3").show();
  });

});
```

Rough visual
Most likely will load images at the end of the page to reduce lag, also pages will be split up to about 10 on a page
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbkSR.png]

Comment: You can use an iterator to construct the ids dynamically. Something like for(i = 1; i < itemCount; i++){ //$("#thumb" + i +"-1,#thumb" + i + "-2,#thumb" + i + "-3").hover(function() {...} }
Here's a doc on the javascript For loop. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I will look into that. Could you give me an example from how the first units IDs would count to the second then third?

Comment: Note that in my example above, itemCount would be a variable that was set outside the loop. I'm presuming that it could be dynamic, but if it's always a known number you could hardcode it, "i < 90" for example.

Comment: it will be better if your content is generated by server side such as php instead of javascript.

Comment: It looks like it should actually be the reverse of what I did in my initial example. If you know it always going to be 1-i, 2-i, 3-i then just hardcode that part. I've built it here in a fiddle (obviously without the markup it won't work).
http://jsfiddle.net/tbkLua3z/

Comment: @wlin That's a matter of opinion. There are advantages and disadvantages to it, but it's not for us to prescribe.

Comment: @Mic can't really find any advantage with js generated content. without a fallback which defeat the purpose of David don't want to manually type in 90 list.

Comment: @wlin Reduced server load. Yes, there are definitely trade-offs. But neither you or I have enough background information to judge whether it's worth the trade-off.

Comment: I am helping out a family member for a small site, they want the most simply thing to use, and it would be easier for them to edit content in notepad than go through maintaining something using PHP

Comment: @Mic I feel so stupid. Only right now did I realise that I could do a for loop.  I feel so so stupid haha. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8k5L5myo/2/

```
var totalImageTypeCount = 10;
var defaultImageCount = 1;
var thumbImageCount = 3;
var overlayImageCount = 2;
var wrapper = $(".wrapper");
var defaultTag = '<div class=".defaultTag"> this is default';
var overlayTag = '<div class=".overlayTag"> this is oeverlay';
var thumbTag = '<div class=".thumbTag"> this is Thumbnail';
var closeTag = "</div>";

for (var a = 0; a < totalImageTypeCount; a++) {
    wrapper.append(defaultTag);

    for (var b = 0; b < overlayImageCount; b++) {

        wrapper.append(overlayTag);
        wrapper.append(closeTag);
    }

    for (var c = 0; c < thumbImageCount; c++) {
                    wrapper.append(thumbTag);
                    wrapper.append(closeTag);
        }
    wrapper.append(closeTag);

}
```

use for loop to loop through all the image to you need, you can use `src=-"dir/yourImage"+a+".jpg"` where `a` will loop though 1-max number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation right, this should work.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "[id^=thumb]", function(e) {
  $(this).show();
  var itemno = $(this).attr("id").replace("thumb","").replace("/-\d+/","");
  $("#default"+itemno).hide();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "[id^=thumb]", function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
  var itemno = $(this).attr("id").replace("thumb","").replace("/-\d+/","");
  $("#default"+itemno).show();
});
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what any of that means.

Comment: It is a piece of code that handles the `hover` (which is just a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events) of all thumbs instead of binding them to all your elements seperately.